# I replaced old ceiling light with new LED. Now it doesn't work, help?

Tags: light-fixture

Replacing old ceiling light with LED. There are two switches, and two recessed lights that the ceiling light works in conjunction with. I turned one light switch off, and disconnected old light. it has a bare wire, with a black wire and a white wire, New light has black and white only. LED doesn't work. I reconnected old light that worked before hand, and it'snot working either. What did I do?

Comment: Forgot to turn the power back on? That or "made a bad connection" are the first two things to check.

Comment: The bare wire is ground, it is there for your safety only, most lights do not use/have connections for ground.  Working with light's wires by just turning off by a switch is not good for your health, you got lucky.

Answer (score 2):

"There are two switches, and two recessed lights that the ceiling light works in conjunction with. I turned one light switch off, and disconnected old light.

It sounds like you have a 3way switch setup. try turning on the other switch.
OR
You may have disturbed the wiring for the 3way in the Jbox in the ceiling.

Getting a pic to us so we may see what you are dealing with would be a great help.